# Extrañas lineas en una grid (WPF, XAML,C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, xaml, grid

tengo un problema y no encuentro solución.

Creando una grid, y rellenando los bordes de esta Grid con elementos Border para ponerle un fondo individual a cada una de las celdas de la grid, me he encontrado con el problema de que surgen estas lineas extrañas que no encuentro la manera de eliminar.

Si hago bastante zoomin, las lineas desaparecen, pero al volver a hacer zoomout vuelven a aparecer. El problema es que cuando ejecuto el programa se siguen viendo y no se que solucion ponerle.

Alguien tiene idea de porque sucede en algunas si en algunas no, y posibles soluciones?

Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<Grid x:Name="Board"">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <!--BORDES DEL TABLERO-->

        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="9"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="10"/>

        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="4"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="5"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="6"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="7"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="8"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="9"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="10"/>

        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="3"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="4"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="5"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="6"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="7"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="8"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="9"/>

        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="8"/>
        <Border Background="#79521E" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="9"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que buscas hacer sería algo así:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="10">
    <Grid/>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes utilizar UseLayoutRounding="True" dentro del tag de Window / UserControl

```
<UserControl UseLayoutRounding="True"> </UserControl>
```

OR

```
<Window UseLayoutRounding="True"> </Window>
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.uselayoutrounding?view=netframework-4.8

Saludos.